# get all the children whose grandparent's ID is equal to 1

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I have three tables in database as follows:

```
1.Design_Master_ParentMenus
    1.ParentMenuID      1--------
    2.Title                     |
2.Design_Master_Categories      |
    1.CategoryID         1------|---------
    2.Title                     |        |
    3.ParentMenuID        *------        |
3.Design_Master_TileItem                 |
    1.TileItemID                         | 
    2.Title                              |
    3.CategoryID          *---------------
```

Now I want to get all the Items from `Master_Design_TileItem` whose grandparent's ParentMenuID is equal to 1.

So, far I have tried the below queries but I was not successful.

```
var g = from f in db.Design_Master_Categories
        where f.CategoryID == 1
        select f.CategoryID;

var v = from h in db.Design_Master_ParentMenus
        where h.ParentMenuID == g.FirstOrDefault()
        select h.ParentMenuID;

var result = from t in db.Design_Master_TileItem
             join c in db.Design_Master_Categories
             on t.CategoryID equals c.CategoryID
             join p in db.Design_Master_ParentMenus
             on c.ParentMenuID equals p.ParentMenuID
             where p.ParentMenuID == v.FirstOrDefault()
             select t;
```

But when I run the program I always get result = null.

Comment: `where f.CategoryID == 1 select f.CategoryID`. Are you trying to determine existence of a valid ID? Same with declaring `v`, and `g`, they will always be `1`

Comment: @BradM what do you mean by above comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How does

```
    where f.CategoryID == 1
```

condition follows

> Now I want to get all the Items from `Master_Design_TileItem` whose grandparent's **`ParentMenuID` is equal to 1**.

? You said, you want `ParentMenuID = 1`, not `CategoryID = 1`.

You also didn't say how is your model set, but with proper navigation properties, you should be able to do:

```
var result = from c in db.Design_Master_Categories
             from i in c.TileItems
             where c.ParentMenuID == 1
             select i;
```

Comment: Your query works and the answer to your question is that I have got a TileItem whose ID = 1. I know it's ParentID is also 1 and its grand parent ID is also 1. So I asked it directly. Yes Thank you for a fast reply.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your database set up correctly it should be as easy as:

```
Design_Master_TileItems.Where(x => x.Design_Master_Category.ParentMenuId == 1)
```